# How to get style sheet property value by webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I want to know whether content menu of drop down is displayed or none. I want to click on that menu if it's display none. and keep as it is if blocked. the property value is like this:

**div id="section_content_23" class="thread-content" style="display: none;"** i have xpath of title is like ex 'section_title_23'. i just want to know the style is  "display: none;" or style = "display: blocked";
I have write code for this like:

else if (str.contains("section_title_"))
            {

```
            //String xpath;
            String[] retval = str.split("_", 3);
            String no = retval[2];
        //  

            displaylinkhandler = QuickCap.driver.findElement(By.id("section_content_" + no)).getAttribute("style");



            //displaylinkhandler = QuickCap.driver.findElement(By.id("section_content_" + no)).getAttribute("section_content_"+no);
            //displaylinkhandler = QuickCap.driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).getText();
            //boolean show = displaylinkhandler.contains("display: none;");
            if(displaylinkhandler == null){
                QuickCap.driver.findElement(By.xpath(str)).click();         
            }
            indexBoolean = TitleCheck.validate();

        }
```

here str is xpath & displaylinkhandler is like string.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

did you tried getCssValue from webelement.
for instance: `ele.getCssValue("propname")`
By the way to check element is displayed or not you should user isDisplayed method of webelement

Answer (score 1):

In webdriver we use

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("elementName"));
```

and then

```
String attributeValue = element.getAttribute("attributeName");
```

So in your case it will

```
String styleValue = element.getAttribute("style");
```